# Nominate library directory at compilation

Tags: linux, macos, unix, installation, gnu-make

I was able to generate an executable using

gcc myexec -o obj1.obj -o obj2.obj ...and link xxx.dylib

I deploy myexec to a different machine. myexec, ofcourse, would need xxx.dylib to run.

For that, I create myInstallFolder with xxx.dylib and myexec

On deployment, I was able to make myexec pick xxx.dylib by setting DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH point to myInstallFolder.

However, I want to avoid using DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH.

What change should be done at compilation/linking to make myexec pick up from myInstallFolder?

~Ryder

Comment: If you expect to be using gcc frequently, 1. read up on gmake and its associated makefiles, 2. change one of the tags on your posting to gmake. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can instruct the linker to write a path into the binary that the loader will use to load .so files:

```
-Wl,-R<path to myInstallFolder>
```

For example

```
-Wl,-R/usr/local/mybin/lib
```

Comment: I tried Wl, -L/usr/local/lib in vain. I will try with -R. However, when I need to deploy myexec to say 100 systems, how I could nominate such directory that guarantees existence?

Comment: @user1385988 To know that a specific directory exists, you check for it and create it if it's not there. This is typically done using some kind of install script. If you're going to package your binary (.deb, .rpm) you need to learn how to do it in this context.

Comment: @user1385988 And just to avoid confusion: if you are placing your library in `/usr/local/lib`, the need for `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and other tricks like `-R` just isn't there. This path is typically part of the pre-defined places to look for .so files. But you might need to run `ldconfig` after placing your library there to let the loader see it.